# How to remove margin from centered navbar logo to give links more space

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a navbar with a centered logo, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the `margin` on either side of the logo, I think it's because `flex` evens out the three `sections` of the `nav`?

**This is what I have:**
[Navbar with required sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Vlu.png)

Is it possible to set a `%` size in CSS or similar to Bootstrap's `col` size so that I can have something like this;

```
  col-5   |  col-2  |    col-5

  links   |   logo  |    links
```

I've tried setting the container section for the image to a specific size or percentage but that makes the image smaller.

I have [made a codepen here](https://codepen.io/grabthereef/pen/YzzdwMX).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-no-bg" role="navigation">    
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100" id="top-navbar-1">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
      <li class="nav-item mr-3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/tours">Virtual 360° Tours</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/photos">Photography</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/photos">Photography</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <section id="nav-logo-image" class="nav-logo center ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x55" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    </a>
  </section>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100" id="top-navbar-1">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
      <li class="nav-item mr-3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/drones">Drone Photography</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/design">Web Design</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/design">Web Design</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div> 

  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-sm mr-4" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-navbar-1" aria-controls="top-navbar-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the .center class and logo image sizing. You probably want to restructure the Navbar to get the correct order and alignment on mobile too.

Simplified it to: https://codeply.com/p/XtQAeldyEX

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-no-bg" role="navigation">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-sm mr-4" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-navbar-1" aria-controls="top-navbar-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100" id="top-navbar-1">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-lg-auto ml-3">
            ..
        </ul>
    </div>
    <section id="nav-logo-image" class="order-first order-lg-0 nav-logo">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-3" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x55" class="img-flud" alt="">
        </a>
    </section>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100" id="top-navbar-1">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-lg-auto ml-lg-0 ml-3">
            ..
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is it possible using this method to spread the links out evenly to the outside edge?

Answer (score 1):

That is not a margin gap. You set the logo to align centre to the section div. This is because of the logo image. The image has `max-width: 100%` so it tries to accommodate in given width without changing the aspect ratio (dimensions) of the image.

Try with a bigger width image and set the `width: 100%` to the anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting width:100% on a flex item that is probably dividing the whole div into three equal parts remove `w-100` from the html and remove `width:100%` from class `.center`, this should remove the unwanted margins